# MYSQL Select all that do not equal something

Tags: mysql

Im having a bit of difficulty with one equation I can't seem to figure out or find on here. I am trying to do the following;

I have 2 tables, products and teamproducts. There  foreign key is productid. I am trying to select the products from the products table that have not been registered to the teamproducts table. I am also using a teamcode that in teamproducts. An example below;

### products Table (productid | productname)

1001 | product 1

1002 | product 2

1003 | product 3

1004 | product 4

1005 | product 5

etc

### teamproducts Table (teamcode | productid)

teamcode1 | 1001

teamcode1 | 1002

What I want to do is select all the products that aren't in the teamproducts page (so in this example product 3 and on)

I have tried the following;

```
    SELECT productname FROM products p, teamproducts tp WHERE teamcode = teamcode1 AND p.productid != tp.productid
```

and other variations I have seen but have not come up with the right line. Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I think this should do the job.

```
SELECT products.productname
FROM products
LEFT JOIN teamproducts
  ON teamproducts.teamcode = 'teamcode1'
  AND teamproducts.productid = products.productid
WHERE teamproducts.productid IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `LEFT JOIN`, with an extra condition that eliminates the null results from the right table:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
LEFT JOIN teamproducts USING (productid) 
WHERE teamproducts.productid IS NULL; -- Add other conditions as needed
```

**EDIT** Adding 'teamcode' condition:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
LEFT JOIN teamproducts USING (productid) 
WHERE teamproducts.productid IS NULL 
AND teamproducts.teamcode = 'teamcode1'; -- Add other conditions as needed
```

More about JOIN, and different types of it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: This works until I try to add the teamcode parameter, then I do not get any results. Any suggestions?

Comment: I edited the answer to add the condition of teamcode.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write `teamcode1` between quotes.
Something like this:

```
SELECT productname FROM products p, teamproducts tp WHERE teamcode = 'teamcode1' AND p.productid != tp.productid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a not in clause

```
select * from products
where id not in (select productid from teamproduct);
```

Comment: With the risk that MySQL can't optimise the query as good as with a `LEFT JOIN`, because of the subselect.